# Loop over a JSON not picking up all values

Tags: python, json

I am trying to return each highlight's 'blurb' and 'FLASH_1800K_896x504' url. To do this, I am running this loop below:

```
import requests
game_url = "http://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/2021030321/content"
team_response = requests.get(game_url)
js = team_response.json()
newdata = js['highlights']['gameCenter']['items']
for item in newdata:
    print(item['blurb'])
    print(item['playbacks'][3]['url'])
```

After doing a Ctrl-F on the data file, I am expecting 51 results. However, only 15 are being returned. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I get a 403 when running your code, without seeing the data it will be hard to answer your question.

Comment: Please post the data that trigger the issue.

Comment: Why are you expecting 51 results? i only see 15 elements in the "items" array

Comment: Hmm, I get 15 results printed out.

Comment: The string `FLASH_1800K_896x504` does exist 51 times in the file, but there not all in gameCenter. So yea you wont find them all like so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like not all occurence of "FLASH_1800K_896x504" exist in the path that you're logging, try exploring futher more your json file